# How to sketch the graph of an inverse function?

Tags: graphing-functions

> Given the function $f(x)=x^2$
>
> i) Write $f^{-1}(x)$ in the form of $y$
>
> ii) Sketch the graph $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x+1)$ on the same set of axes
>
> iii) Use your graphs to solve for $x$ if $\log_2(x+2) < 1$

Now looking at the solution, the graph shows that the Inverse function going through the point $(1,0)$ so what i don't understand is that how did they get to the mentioned point if no value of $x$ or $y$ is given (so I could plug $y$ OR $x$ into the equation and and find $x$ & $y$ values in order to sketch the graph?

Comment: That's weird. The inverse function of $f(x) = x^2$ doesn't pass through $(1,0)$ because $0^2 = 0 \neq 1$ ...

Comment: @Samir: Is I am doing anything wrong on the edit?

Comment: Also the question is unclear. Usually, in order to sketch the graph of a function, you can choose the values of the independent variable (usually $x$) freely. It's best to choose "easy" values, for example $0$ and $1$, etc. This obviously depends of the function ...

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is a function iff $f$ is one one

Comment: Because the last point involves logarithms, perhaps there is a mistake on the question: Is it really $x^2$ and not $2^x$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order for an inverse function to be defined you must find if the initial function is 1-1, meaning that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2.$
Once you've checked that you take into account this: The main function and the inverse function happen to have the following property (The proof is very obvious if you consider the meaning of the inverse function): Their axis of symmetry is the line $y=x$. So when trying to sketch its graph you just find the symmetrical line with regard to $f(x)$ having as axis of symmetry the straight line $y=x$.